How can I may in xbindkeys both Alts to a specific keybinding?
What title says, I am trying to set them both in .xbindkeysrc.
I want to use this keybind to rotate between keyboard layouts, since it is a comfortable but unlikely combination to accidentally press.
Using the syntax:
"some_bash_command"
    [Alt + ]Alt_R + Alt_L 

Alt + Alt_R + Alt_L -> command gets ignored
Alt_R + Alt_L -> results in the command being run on every left alt, effectively overruning any Alt_L keybinding and making Alt_R not do anything.
pkill xbindkeys && xbindkeys -> Using this to debug

Interestingly enough this is when you debug using --multikey:
"(Scheme function)" 
m:0x8 + c:108 
Alt + Alt_R 
"(Scheme function)" 
m:0x8 + c:64 
Alt + Alt_L 

I guess something particular on xbindkeys just does not allow for both alts to be inputted synchronously.
No clue as to why Pressing only AltLeft gets fully overridden.

It might be not xbindkeys, but your keyboard. Usually keyboards have very limited number of lines. Only good keyboards support every key multipress.

That would be the case, except I have set up this exact key shortcut before using a desktop utility (in cinnamon desktop) and it worked as intended.
